I don't want to have a src folder in my dist foler
I'm using vite in a project and my folder structure is like this
youtube_comments/
   src/
    js/
     script.js
    sass/
     styles.sass
   index.html

When i move the index.html file in the root to the src folder and convert
 rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      },
    },

to
 rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html'),
      },

there appears to be a src folder in my dist folder
although i want my index.html to be in the root of the dist foler

First,
You can use the outputDir property along with Rollup’s plugin or use the build option to control how paths are handled:
Second,
Ensure that the file paths are updated correctly when moving files from the src folder to dist. You might need to manually manage certain files if the output structure still keeps the folder nesting.

It's vite actually not rollup
